# Controlling the syncSourceHost of a MongoDb replica set

Tags: mongodb

We have a high-end replica set cluster with several members.
The primary is very loaded, so we enabled the chaining settings which enable members to sync from a secondary member.
Our problem is that once in a while the secondary gets very loaded (we use it for queries) and then the other members suffer from high replication lags.
I was wondering if there is a way to control the syncSourceHost in a way that a specific member will be chosen? or is there in general a good approach for solving it?
From reading https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/replica-set-sync/#std-label-replica-set-replication-sync-source-selection it seems the process is mostly automatic and doesn't provide much control on the source election.

Comment: Consider a sharded cluster in order to distribute the load.

Comment: I wonder if a hidden node is also hidden for chaining purposes. i.e. cannot be used as syncSource.

Comment: One of the rules in sync source selection is: The sync source must be visible. So a hidden member won't help. But @AlexBlex, are you aware of a way of controlling the source member? Because if that is possible, I can have a dedicated member for that. But if I can't control which member it will be, I can't choose the idle one.

Comment: But this is exactly what I had in mind, just couldn't find the line that says the sync source must be visible. Hide secondaries that you query from app layer.  Since chain reads always go to visible member, they won't clash with app reads, right? Just to make it clear, I couldn't find any traces syncSources are configurable.